# text-align: justify + left

Tags: alignment, css, justify

I have a code like this:
HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>some</div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>here</div>
    <div>...</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div>some</div>
    <div>text</div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#container {
    text-align: justify;
}

#container:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

#container > div {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1odgx6vq/

I need the blocks to be justified, because they have fixed width, but I need to "align left" in the second container. Is there a way to do this?
Thanks for replies.

EDIT:
I tried to fix it with JS by adding an element with inherited background, that works when I add it manually in HTML code, but with JS it doesn't re-align, demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/1odgx6vq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding a space *before* and after the javascript-added element